# How to convert MYSQL Query to support with Derby database

Tags: mysql, derby

I used below mention query to cerate report in My Project with MYSQL with Java NetBeans. It works successfully.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sortId = 1 THEN CAST(orderId AS CHAR(10)) ELSE '' END AS orderId, CASE WHEN sortId = 
1 THEN orderName ELSE '' END AS orderName, itemName, itemUnit, itemRate
FROM
(
SELECT orderId, orderName, itemName, itemUnit, itemRate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId 
ORDER BY itemId) AS sortId
FROM
(
    SELECT orderId, orderName, itemName, itemUnit, itemRate, itemId
    FROM tblitem 
    INNER JOIN  tblorder 
        on tblorder.orderId = tblitem.orderRef
) orderItems
) orderItemsSorted
ORDER BY orderItemsSorted.orderId, orderItemsSorted.sortId
```

Later I wanted to use Derby Database in Netbeans. When I attempted to use that Query makes error message

```
Syntax error: Encountered "PARTITION" at line 4, column 81.
```

To avoid this problem can I use "The result offset and fetch first clauses" in Derby?
Thanks in advance to help me to convert or change this query to work in Derby.
I Below mentioned table creation and join Quires

TBLORDER (Order Table)

```
  CREATE TABLE TBLORDER (
  ORDERID INTEGER,
  ORDERNAME VARCHAR (50),
  PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID)
  );
```

[image: Order Table]

TBLITEM (Item Table)

```
  CREATE TABLE TBLITEM (
  ITEMID INTEGER,
  ITEMNAME VARCHAR (50),
  ITEMUNIT VARCHAR (10),
  ITEMRATE DOUBLE,
  ORDERREF INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (ITEMID)
  );
```

[image: Item Table]

CREATE FOREIGN KEY

```
  ALTER TABLE NAME.TBLITEM
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (ORDERREF)
  REFERENCES NAME.TBLORDER (ORDERID)
```

JOIN QUERY

```
  SELECT ORDERID, ORDERNAME, ITEMNAME, ITEMUNIT, ITEMRATE
  FROM TBLITEM 
  INNER JOIN  TBLORDER 
  ON TBLORDER.ORDERID = TBLITEM.ORDERREF
```

[image: After Joining]

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: I use MYSQL 8.0 and Derby 10.10 (with NetBeans 8.2RC Version) Sorry for my late comment

Comment: I don't want to try to understand that query since `orderId` is overloaded.  That is, I can't tell whether orderId is the column or the alias.  Please use a different term for the alias.

Comment: I don't think Derby supports window functions, so you'll have to find another way of doing what you want, e.g. format output in your application instead.

Comment: @ Rick James I edit my question for more clearness and posted as a result what I expect from MYSQL Query. When I search internet I found PARTITION BY keyword not support by Derby. Then what will be the solution to solve my problem in Derby?

Comment: @mustaccio Tks I will Try to that solution also.